Why are lists performing faster than numpy arrays in my n-body integrator?
I made a simple n-body integrator using Euler's method in python. I didn't know about numpy arrays, so I treated each vector as a list of x, y, and z variables. I even made my own magnitude() function from scratch to square and add the values together. I was suggested to use numpy arrays: it would make my code look cleaner, I wouldn't constantly be dealing with three variables, and it would be faster. It was indeed all of those things, except it was slower. 2x slower.
Here's the code for the one with lists:
print('Initializing...')

import math
import time
import calendar

dt=1

class Body:
  def __init__(self, pos, vel, acc, GM, color):
    self.pos = pos
    self.vel = vel
    self.acc = acc
    self.GM = GM
    self.color = color

sun=Body(
  [0,0,0],
  [0,0,0],
  [],
  1.32712440041279419e20, #1.32712440018e20 #1.3271244004193938e20
  'orange')  
mercury=Body(
  [-4.108411877039495E+07,2.997375954154480E+07,6.217890408222714E+06],
  [-3.865743010383652E+01,-3.733889075044869E+01,4.944436024774976E-01],
  [],
  2.2031868551E+13,
  'black')
venus=Body(
  [-1.069987422398024E+08,-1.145572515113905E+07,6.016588327139664E+06],
  [3.513460276994624E+00,-3.497755629371660E+01,-6.830913209445484E-01],
  [],
  3.24858592000E+14,
  'yellow')
earth=Body(
  [-2.481099325965390E+07,1.449948612736719E+08,-8.215203670851886E+03],
  [-2.984146365518679E+01,-5.126262286859617E+00,1.184224839788195E-03],
  [],
  3.98600435507E+14, #3.98600435436E+14
  'blue')
mars=Body(
  [-4.388577457389553E+07,-2.170849264747288E+08,-3.473007284527391E+06],
  [2.466191455174334E+01,-5.594344409323426E+00,4.240886274745919E-01],
  [],
  4.2828375816E+13, #4.2828375214E+13
  'red')
jupiter=Body( #Barycenter
  [5.225707808892267E+08,5.318268084719173E+08,-1.390073672466460E+07],
  [-9.479547147917305E+00,9.781812771839792E+00,1.714496767625100E-01],
  [],
  1.26712764100000E+17, #1.26686531900E+17
  'brown')
saturn=Body( #Barycenter
  [1.345793470545739E+09,-5.559292621384816E+08,-4.389272824857706E+07],
  [3.145491294741479E+00,8.918908096728853E+00,-2.803661611085468E-01],
  [],
  3.7940584841800E+16, #3.7931206234E+16
  'green')
uranus=Body( #Barycenter
  [1.835714287613103E+09,2.288891426581001E+09,-1.529866616820955E+07],
  [-5.371909870919789E+00,3.954382268177655E+00,8.420336496942427E-02],
  [],
  5.794556400000E+15, #5.793951256E+15
  'cyan')
neptune=Body( #Barycenter
  [4.464446478443181E+09,-2.679156449818206E+08,-9.736552658539964E+07],
  [2.818332382913437E-01,5.469932267577336E+00,-1.190017337507621E-01],
  [],
  6.836527100580E+15, #6.83509997E+15
  'darkblue')
moon=Body(
  [-2.517894579079584E+07,1.451613930689555E+08,1.696211394185573E+04],
  [-3.025123150480888E+01,-6.001889331002243E+00,-5.808094571415667E-02],
  [],
  4.902800118E+12, #4.902800066E+12
  'gray')
#Pos Vel Data: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/app.html#/
#GM Data: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/astro_par.html


bodies=[sun,mercury,venus,earth,mars,jupiter,saturn,uranus,neptune,moon]

#functions

def magnitude(x,y,z):
  return math.sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)


def grav_acc(body1,body2):
  r = magnitude(
    body2.pos[0] - body1.pos[0],
    body2.pos[1] - body1.pos[1],
    body2.pos[2] - body1.pos[2])
  a=body2.GM/math.pow(r*1000,2)/1000
  return (
    (body2.pos[0]-body1.pos[0])/r*a,
    (body2.pos[1]-body1.pos[1])/r*a,
    (body2.pos[2]-body1.pos[2])/r*a)


def total_acc(body_number):
    body=bodies[body_number]
    body.acc=[0,0,0]
    for i in range(len(bodies)):
      if i != body_number:
        acc_data=grav_acc(body,bodies[i])
        body.acc[0]+=acc_data[0]
        body.acc[1]+=acc_data[1]
        body.acc[2]+=acc_data[2]
        
      

def suvat(body_number):
    total_acc(body_number)
    body=bodies[body_number]
   
    body.pos[0]+=body.vel[0]*dt+0.5*body.acc[0]*math.pow(dt,2)
    body.pos[1]+=body.vel[1]*dt+0.5*body.acc[1]*math.pow(dt,2)
    body.pos[2]+=body.vel[2]*dt+0.5*body.acc[2]*math.pow(dt,2)
  
    body.vel[0]+=body.acc[0]*dt
    body.vel[1]+=body.acc[1]*dt
    body.vel[2]+=body.acc[2]*dt


def timestep():
  for i in range(len(bodies)):
    suvat(i)

print('Initialization Complete!\n\nInitial Data:\n')
print(earth.pos)
print(earth.vel)
print(earth.acc,'\n')


days=input('Days: ')
start_time=calendar.timegm(time.strptime("01 Jan 24", "%d %b %y"))

print('\nStart!\n')
start_time = time.time()
for x in range (0,int(float(days)*(24*60*60)/dt)):
  if x*dt/24/60/60 % 1 == 0:
    print("Day",int(x*dt/24/60/60))
    print("Earth:\n",earth.pos)
    print(earth.vel)
    print(earth.acc)
    print("\nSun:")
    print(sun.pos)
    print(sun.vel)
    print(sun.acc)
  else:
    timestep() #<-- the important thing

print(int(days),'\nComplete!\n\nEarth Data:\n')
end_time = time.time()
print("Total Time: ", end_time-start_time)
print(earth.pos)
print(earth.vel)
print(earth.acc)
print("\nSun:")
print(sun.pos)
print(sun.vel)
print(sun.acc)


And here's the code for the one using numpy:
print('Initializing...')

import math
import time
import calendar

import numpy as np


dt=1

class Body:
  def __init__(self, pos, vel, acc, GM, color):
    self.pos = pos
    self.vel = vel
    self.acc = acc
    self.GM = GM
    self.color = color

sun=Body(
  np.array([0,0,0]),
  np.array([0,0,0]),
  np.array([0,0,0]),
  1.32712440041279419e20, #1.32712440018e20 #1.3271244004193938e20
  'orange')  
mercury=Body(
  np.array([-4.108411877039495E+07,2.997375954154480E+07,6.217890408222714E+06]),
  np.array([-3.865743010383652E+01,-3.733889075044869E+01,4.944436024774976E-01]),
  np.array([0,0,0]),
  2.2031868551E+13,
  'black')
venus=Body(
  np.array([-1.069987422398024E+08,-1.145572515113905E+07,6.016588327139664E+06]),
  np.array([3.513460276994624E+00,-3.497755629371660E+01,-6.830913209445484E-01]),
  np.array([0,0,0]),
  3.24858592000E+14,
  'yellow')
earth=Body(
  np.array([-2.481099325965390E+07,1.449948612736719E+08,-8.215203670851886E+03]),
  np.array([-2.984146365518679E+01,-5.126262286859617E+00,1.184224839788195E-03]),
  np.array([0,0,0]),
  3.98600435507E+14, #3.98600435436E+14
  'blue')
mars=Body(
  np.array([-4.388577457389553E+07,-2.170849264747288E+08,-3.473007284527391E+06]),
  np.array([2.466191455174334E+01,-5.594344409323426E+00,4.240886274745919E-01]),
  np.array([0,0,0]),
  4.2828375816E+13, #4.2828375214E+13
  'red')
jupiter=Body( #Barycenter
  np.array([5.225707808892267E+08,5.318268084719173E+08,-1.390073672466460E+07]),
  np.array([-9.479547147917305E+00,9.781812771839792E+00,1.714496767625100E-01]),
  np.array([0,0,0]),
  1.26712764100000E+17, #1.26686531900E+17
  'brown')
saturn=Body( #Barycenter
  np.array([1.345793470545739E+09,-5.559292621384816E+08,-4.389272824857706E+07]),
  np.array([3.145491294741479E+00,8.918908096728853E+00,-2.803661611085468E-01]),
  np.array([0,0,0]),
  3.7940584841800E+16, #3.7931206234E+16
  'green')
uranus=Body( #Barycenter
  np.array([1.835714287613103E+09,2.288891426581001E+09,-1.529866616820955E+07]),
  np.array([-5.371909870919789E+00,3.954382268177655E+00,8.420336496942427E-02]),
  np.array([]),
  5.794556400000E+15, #5.793951256E+15
  'cyan')
neptune=Body( #Barycenter
  np.array([4.464446478443181E+09,-2.679156449818206E+08,-9.736552658539964E+07]),
  np.array([2.818332382913437E-01,5.469932267577336E+00,-1.190017337507621E-01]),
  np.array([0,0,0]),
  6.836527100580E+15, #6.83509997E+15
  'darkblue')
moon=Body(
  np.array([-2.517894579079584E+07,1.451613930689555E+08,1.696211394185573E+04]),
  np.array([-3.025123150480888E+01,-6.001889331002243E+00,-5.808094571415667E-02]),
  np.array([0,0,0]),
  4.902800118E+12, #4.902800066E+12
  'gray')
#Pos Vel Data: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/app.html#/
#GM Data: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/astro_par.html


bodies=[sun,mercury,venus,earth,mars,jupiter,saturn,uranus,neptune,moon]

#functions

def grav_acc(body1,body2):
  r = np.linalg.norm(body2.pos-body1.pos)
  a=body2.GM/math.pow(r*1000,2)/1000
  return ((body2.pos-body1.pos)/r*a)


def total_acc(body_number):
    body=bodies[body_number]
    body.acc=[0,0,0]
    for i in range(len(bodies)):
      if i != body_number:
        acc_data=grav_acc(body,bodies[i])
        body.acc = body.acc + acc_data
        
      

def suvat(body_number):
    total_acc(body_number)
    body=bodies[body_number]
   
    body.pos= body.pos + body.vel*dt+ 0.5 * body.acc* math.pow(dt,2)
    body.vel=body.vel + body.acc*dt


def timestep():
  for i in range(len(bodies)):
    suvat(i)

 
print('Initialization Complete!\n\nInitial Data:\n')
print(earth.pos)
print(earth.vel)
print(earth.acc,'\n')


days=input('Days: ')
start_time=calendar.timegm(time.strptime("01 Jan 24", "%d %b %y"))

print('\nStart!\n')
start_time = time.time()
for x in range (0,int(float(days)*(24*60*60)/dt)):
  if x*dt/24/60/60 % 1 == 0:
    print("Day",int(x*dt/24/60/60))
    print("Earth:\n",earth.pos)
    print(earth.vel)
    print(earth.acc)
    print("\nSun:")
    print(sun.pos)
    print(sun.vel)
    print(sun.acc)
  else:
    timestep() #<-- the important thing

print(int(days),'\nComplete!\n\nEarth Data:\n')
end_time = time.time()
print("Total Time: ", end_time-start_time)
print(earth.pos)
print(earth.vel)
print(earth.acc)
print("\nSun:")
print(sun.pos)
print(sun.vel)
print(sun.acc)


My results for one simulated day using lists was:
Complete!

Earth Data:

Total Time:  23.128202438354492
[-27385404.548457384, 144529451.5861996, -8105.186673260389]
[-29.74987226023974, -5.646917018209525, 0.0013563469814852206]
[1.112851770138038e-06, -6.019252799282894e-06, 1.7747241298097921e-09]

and for numpy:
Complete!

Earth Data:

Total Time:  52.90268087387085
[-2.73854045e+07  1.44529452e+08 -8.10518667e+03]
[-2.97498723e+01 -5.64691702e+00  1.35634698e-03]
[ 1.11285177e-06 -6.01925280e-06  1.77472413e-09]

As you can see, same results (although less sig figs...?), but much longer time.
A few notes:
dt

1 second for both simulations
All the code is the same, other than use of numpy arrays instead of lists.
Instead of using my magnitude() function for the new version with numpy, I used linalg.norm. I expected this to be faster, maybe it isn't?
All the arrays are 3 dimensional (x,y,z), maybe smaller arrays don't have performance benefits?
All the numpy calculations I am doing are array = array + something, array = array * scalar, array = array / scalar, or linalg.norm(array)

I plan to try multiprocessing and other improvements to speed up simulation time in the future, so I want to make choices that are best for the speed of my code. A quick google search says numpy should be faster, but my results don't match that.

No one here reads crystal balls, we read code... [ask] and [mre]

'All the arrays are 3 dimensional (x,y,z), maybe smaller arrays don't have performance benefits?": are you using the arrays to store just 3 values (coordinates)? Do you use separate arrays for each body? How many bodies / masses are there?

numpy is optimized to do big computations on big arrays. It may have some small overhead cost but this will be easily dwarfed by the later gain, if your code leverages numpy vectorization properly, which we currently have no way to check...

I see you've added the code. As mentioned in other comments, your arrays aren't large enough to merit the use of Numpy (all your arrays are shape (3,)).

So should I just stick with lists? Or is there benefit to using numpy if I 'use it correctly'. If it's the latter, how do I use it correctly to improve performance?

@stookalacka to use it correctly you would need to rething your whole code, so it uses arrays of size 10+. You may also want to take a look at numba package, as it should deal with your code (maybe with some small changes), and Just-In-Time (JIT) compile it and make it magnitudes faster

numpy doesn't play that well with user defined classes like your Body.  Putting the data in a (10,3) shaped aray would let you take (some) advantage of its multidimensionality. Think of it as a 'table'. But even with that you'd be iterating on rows, rather than working with the whole array at once.  Efficient numpy often requires a whole different conceptualization of the data and operations.

Numpy should be faster when compared to list but you need to implemented with vectorisation. A couple of optimisation you can do in your code:

You can rewrite grav_acc and total_acc functions as they takes majority of your code time (Use https://kernprof.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ to profile your code). As I understand you are computing norm and doing normalisation here. Currently, it done for every pair, twice! You can reduce it by half.
It is better to use numpy with vectorisation, otherwise the advantage will be marginal. E.g. With numpy you do not need to compute norm for each vector pair separately. You can define an array of "pos" vectors and compute it in one shot for all pairs.
For e.g. you can do following for vectorised norm calculation:

    import numpy as np
    vectors = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
    diffs = vectors[:, np.newaxis, :] - vectors[np.newaxis, :, :]
    pairwise_norms = np.linalg.norm(diffs, axis=-1)

Hope this helps.
